# Повторение союза "и": перечисление или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Знаменитые строчки Леонида Филатова:

*Утром мажу бутерброд,

Сразу мысль: а как народ?

И икра не лезет в горло(,)

И компот не льется в рот.*

Что-то у меня возникли сомнения насчет запятой после "горло". Нужна она или нет? И вообще, правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в четверостишье?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сомнения понятны. Существующие формализации грамматики не дают возможности однозначно сделать синтаксический анализ данной фразы. 
Первый вариант предполагает рассмотрение первого И как части составного (или повторяющегося) союза "и..., и...", тогда, понятно, запятая нужна. Но возможно также определение первого И как общего для всей фразы союзы или даже усилительной частицы, относящейся ко всей фразе. Тогда второе и - обычный соединительный союз между однородными предложениями, связанными общим членом запятая не ставится. Поскольку смысловых различий между вариантами нет или почти нет, то возникают затруднения в выборе пунктуации.

Если позволено будет воспользоваться скобками, то схемы выглядят так:

**I {И...},{и...}

II И{... и...}**

Насколько могу судить, обычно придерживаются первого варианта пунктуации. Именно так и у автора. Обоснование второго требует очень сильной мотивации (надо видеть в первом и именно одноместный союз или частицу, да еще найти для для двух предложений общий член), здесь её нет.

Насчет остальных знаков. Это один из возможных вариантов. Прямой речи в явном виде я тут не вижу, поэтому вариант с кавычками выглядит на мой вкус хуже. Но если придираться к вопросительному знаку, который по смыслу относится не во всей фразе, а только к "мысли", то ничего другого не останется.

Comment: @behemothus, здесь не только вопросительный знак, но и усилительная частица *"а"*. Поэтому и прямая речь.

Comment: >здесь не только вопросительный знак, но и усилительная частица "а". Поэтому и прямая речь

Не вижу причинно-следственной связи. 
Вряд ли вы всерьёз считаете, что усилительная частица - атрибут только прямой речи, нет?!

А, вроде сообразил. Вы имеете в виду, что без "а" можно было бы трактовать как придаточное, а с ним - толко как прямую речь? Нет, я не об этом. О придаточном тут речи не идёт изначально. Я вижу здесь (что с частицей, что без неё)  т.н. _**несобственно-прямую речь**__.

Answer (score 2):

Довольно часто в стихотворениях авторы нарушают пунктуацию, фиксированную словарями, всё зависит от желания поэта. Если же разбирать данное четверостишие по правилам, то правильно будет так:

> *Утром мажу бутерброд, 
>
> Сразу мысль: "А как народ?"
>
>
>
> И икра не лезет в горло, 
>
> И компот не льется в рот.*

Очевидно, во второй строке прямая речь, которую неплохо и оформить по правилам прямой речи, как я  сделал. Рассмотрим следующее предложение. Мало того что там повторяющийся союз *"и"*, так ещё там два полносоставных предложения, которые даже при наличии одного *"и"* разделялись бы запятой.

Comment: А в этом варианте запятая в конце второй строки не нужна?

Comment: Нет, думаю, не нужна.

Comment: Я не могу представить грамматику (ну или синтасис) предложения, с прямой речью и без запятой после неё. Либо тогда и вторая тоже лишнаяя.  
Можете пояснить структуру предложения, как вы ее видите?

Comment: A: "П?" А.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна! 2 грамматические основы ↓
И икра не лезет в горло, 
И компот не льется в рот.
икра не лезет   компот не льётся.
Грамматические основы разделяются запятой, не путайте с перечислением и..,и...,и.